# Binary Search tree - insertion

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

> You are given a pointer to the root of a binary search tree and a value to be inserted into the tree. Insert this value into its appropriate position in the binary search tree and return the root of the updated binary tree. You just have to complete the function.

I have given my code but one test case is not working. Here is my code:

```
static Node Insert(Node root,int value){
    Node d =root;
    Node q = new Node();
    q.left = null;
    q.right=null;
    q.data = value;
    while(true){
        if(value<d.data){
            if(d.left==null){d.left = q;
                           return root; }
            else{
                d= d.left ;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(value>d.data){
                if(d.right==null){d.right=q;
                                 return root;}
                else d = d.right;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot even fetch the test case sorry on that....

Comment: So this is the code, something is broken in it, but you cannot tell us what?

Comment: but if the value is equals to the d.data so.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing two cases: `value == d.data` and the empty tree.

`value == d.data`: In that case the tree won't be altered in any way, but your code won't break-off and end up in an infinite loop.

Simplest solution would be to insert these lines in the `while`-loop:

```
if(value == d.data)
    return root;
```

The case where the tree is empty is rather implementation-specific, so it's difficult to suggest any solution for this case.

Comment: The missing case is of a initially empty tree.

Comment: @LUGOWright oh, right, i completely forgot about that case. Though that's another case in addition to mine.

Comment: Yes in addition to yours - @Paul